# Not using "is" in a sentence but it still being correct

Tags: grammar, verbs

sorry for the vague title, i'm not sure how to explain it in short.
It pretty much comes down to a lyric but i just want to know if it's grammatically correct and if there is a certain word for it.

So it's about Frank Ocean's chanel where the first lyric is:
"My guy pretty like a girl"
Shouldn't it be "My guy is pretty like a girl"? Please help me out, is there something that allows you to remove certain verbs and still make it a correct sentence? thanks in advance

Comment: Do not look for standard grammaticality or usage in lyrics. Adherence to conventional grammar or usage is not a priority in song lyrics or poetry; deviation from them, in fact, may be the goal.

Answer (score 2):

This type of construction is called "zero copula" or "null copula".  A sentence such as "my guy pretty like a girl" is not considered grammatical in standard English (it would work only if the "be" was implied from the previous sentence, e.g. "yours is red, mine blue"; "your guy is ugly, my guy pretty like a girl").

However, in some varieties of Englis, zero copula is normal: see http://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/null-copula ("Null copula is a highly common feature of African American English (AAE)").